# When is a cached stylesheet refreshed in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, refresh

In a Rails application, if I group several stylesheets into one using caching, will the resulting file be automatically refreshed when one of the stylesheets is updated ?

```
stylesheet_link_tag "style1.css", "style2.css", :cache => "mystyles"
```

And, if not, how can I expire the resulting file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For production environments, just delete all.css from your stylesheets  directory as part of your deployment to have it regenerated using the new files.

In development mode, `ActionController::Base.perform_caching` is false by default so no caching will happen.